# How to automatically add the number in the first row and the number in the first column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sorry if I fail to phrase the question clearly. English is not my first langauge. ( I would appreciate if someone can help me phrase the question in a less ackward way) What I want is something pretty simple. I have a table where the first row and the first column are filled, but the rest of the cells are empty. I am looking for a way to add every number in the first column with every number in the first row and fill it in their respective cells. [image]For example, cell C2 should be filled with "= C1+A2". Obviously I could type in the fomular mannualy, but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel the you can let the program expand a pattern in your spreadsheet by dragging the tiny square in the bottom right corner of your cell. For cell B2, write =$A2+B$1.

For the other cells you can expand the pattern down the column and then down the rows using this method.

Comment: it doesn't work. If I type "=A2+B1" in cell B2 and drag to the right, the cell C2 would show "=B2+C1", rather than what I want, which is "=A2+C1", so I have to use "=$A$2+B1 to fix  A2 when I am draging it to the right, but that way, I have to retype a new fomular when I want to get the result for row 3.

Comment: Ahh you are correct, you need to use dollar signs: http://dedicatedexcel.com/dollar-signs-in-excel-formula/.

Comment: Yup, but since I already fixed the A2 in the fomular, I can't drag it down.So I have to at least type 5 different fomulars to do what I want.

Comment: This works for me =$A2+B$1. You can fix just the row or just the column.

Comment: Thanks! It sounds so simple now that you point that out!